# Fatal Error: Steam needs to be online to update. Please confirm your network connection and try again

Tags: networking, 18.04, steam

I am trying to install steam and get this error message after it updates: [image: Fatal Error: Steam needs to be online to update. Please confirm your network connection and try again] (it does fully install the update).
I also recorded [a video of me trying to install it](https://youtu.be/oprjYBAyhf4)

I am on ubuntu 18.04